# Gitlab clone button and Integrations with custom URL

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I'm using gitlab on a relative url `domain.com/gitlab` behind a reverse proxy, however I'm having some troubles with a few features.

I had to set `external_url=http://<ip-address>:<port>` to be able to access gitlab with my reverse proxy. When I create a project gitlab shows the correct project url in the creation process `https://my.domain.com/gitlab/<username|groupname>/<newprojectname>` as well as in the settings of existing projects. However the clone button still shows `http://<ip-address>:<port>/gitlab/<username|groupname>/<newprojectname>` which of course isn't working. I've added the slack webhook integration to receive updates on merge requests, pushs, etc. and it's the same problem there. The slack messages have links which look something like this `http://<ip-address>:<port>/gitlab/<username|groupname>/<someidentifier>`.

Could this be a problem with the gitlab version or am I missing some settings?

Gitlab `gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.9.4-ce.0`

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
external_url 'http://<server-ip-address>:<docker-port>/gitlab/'
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['<server-ip-address>']
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
  "Host" => "my.domain.com",
  "X-Real-IP" => "$$remote_addr",
  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
}
```

Nginx: `nginx:1.21.6-alpine`

```
##############
##  GITLAB  ##
##############
  location /gitlab/ {
    root /home/git/gitlab/public;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://<server-ip-address>:<docker-port>/gitlab/;

    gzip                    off;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;


    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying this, the following worked for me:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
external_url 'https://my.domain.com/gitlab/'
nginx['listen_port'] = 8929
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
  "Host" => "$$host",
  "X-Real-IP" => "$$remote_addr",
  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
}
```

```
 location /gitlab/ {
    root /home/git/gitlab/public;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://<server-ip-address>:8929/gitlab/;

    gzip                    off;

    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;


    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
  }
```

Comment: You can safely remove that `/gitlab/` suffix from the `proxy_pass` parameter. It won't change anything in functionality, but in nginx terms it mean _strip the `/gitlab/` prefix specified in `location` directive from the request URI and prepend the request URI with the `/gitlab/` prefix specified in `proxy_pass` directive_. It is just an extra CPU cycles spent on this, it is a very fast operation, but still unnecessary one. Using `proxy_pass http://<server-ip-address>:8929;` will work the same way, passing request URI 1:1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [Installing GitLab under a Relative URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html). It involves changing configuration in a few different files.

Comment: Hey @Richard. I tried this but it wasn't working. I've managed to set it up now though. Thanks anyways.